# Summarise based on binary values

Tags: python, pandas

How can I summarize this dataframe.

```
OCT NOV DEC JAN Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Total Sales
0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4825379.818
1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5522382.297
2   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5721183.289
3   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5374047.083
4   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   4917456.971
```

I want it to be in form

```
Month    Sales
JAN    1235
FEB    5454
..     ..
```

..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can multiple by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) extracted column by [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) first, then `sum` rows for `Series`, `rename` for uppercase months names, add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for correct order, [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for nw column name with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
cats = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL',
       'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']

df1 = (df.mul(df.pop('Total Sales'), axis=0)
         .sum()
         .rename(str.upper)
         .reindex(cats)
         .rename_axis('Month')
         .reset_index(name='Sales'))
print (df1)
   Month         Sales
0    JAN  0.000000e+00
1    FEB  2.144299e+07
2    MAR  4.917457e+06
3    APR  0.000000e+00
4    MAY  0.000000e+00
5    JUN  0.000000e+00
6    JUL  0.000000e+00
7    AUG  0.000000e+00
8    SEP  0.000000e+00
9    OCT  0.000000e+00
10   NOV  0.000000e+00
11   DEC  0.000000e+00
```

Comment: Downvoter, if there's something wrong with my answer, please let me know, so I can correct it. Thanks.

Comment: I need them as separate columns

Comment: Give me  a sec pelase.